# Passing variables to insert query in c

Tags: sql, c, variables, insert, arguments

I am trying to insert the packet information into SQL database in C. When I try to skip any one of the source IP or destination IP , the query works fine. But when i try to use them together, destination IP gets printed in the source IP field.

```
char statement[1052],*source_ipAddr=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_src),*destination_ipAddr=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_dst);

snprintf(statement, 1052, "INSERT INTO tbl_name(src_ip,destination_ip) VALUES ('%s','%s')",inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_src),inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_dst));
```

Comment: what is the use of `*source_ipAddr` and `*destination_ipAddr`?

Comment: This will hold the Source and Destination IP Address of the packet  .When I try to remove * from the variables I get a warning like "warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]" and a segmentation fault while executing the program

Comment: ok, but still i don't see any use of them in this code here.

Comment: the return type of `inet_ntoa()` is `char *`, so you need a `char *` variable to hold the return value. That's natural.

Comment: You need to do an alloc, or otherwise define source_ipAddr and destination_ipAddrs as arrays

Comment: I am passing *source_ipAddr and *destination_ipAddr in the below statement snprintf(statement, 1052, "INSERT INTO tbl_name(src_ip,destination_ip) VALUES ('%s','%s')",source_ipAddr,destination_ipAddr);

Comment: char statement[1052]="test", *a=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_src);
char c[20]="1";
strcpy(c,a);
char *b=inet_ntoa(iphdr->ip_dst);  
snprintf(statement, 1052, "INSERT INTO tblname(ip1,ip2) VALUES ('%s','%s')",c,b);
printf("%s\n,statement);
This prints the values of a and b correctly, bt when i try to remove the  second and third line , the values are not printed as expected

Comment: The mistake is inet_ntoa() returns a pointer to static buffer which is overwritten.